# Unpacking data packets in c++

Tags: c++, printing

I'm doing a udp client server model thing and my issue basically comes down to not being able to print the number 65000 in this short program. The output I get is: `0`

```
struct pHeader{
  uint16_t from = -1;
} pHead;

void formatPacket(pHeader header, char buffer[]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    u16 = header.from;  
    memcpy(buffer+2, &u16, 2);
}

int main () {
cout << "buffer" << endl;

char buffer[10];

pHead.from = 65000;
formatPacket(pHead, buffer);

cout << atoi(buffer+2) << endl; 
}
```

The next thing I want to do is print off a value that's in the first element of the array that's also 16 bits.  I believe it's done like this:

```
.
.
.
buffer[2] = 0;
cout << atoi(buffer+0) << endl;
```

Comment: what makes you believe that the reverse of `memcpy()` is `atoi()` ?

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag? It's C with cout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of `atoi()`, it will return zero "if no valid conversion could be performed".  So, the zero you are seeing is `atoi()` telling you that in the buffer that you gave it there was nothing that it could interpret as a number.

That's because the buffer was filled with `memcpy()` using `&u16` with a size of `2`.  `u16` was 65000, so assuming a little-endian architecture, buffer[2] was `E8`, and buffer[3] was `FD`. That's not a number that `atoi()` can parse.

In order to read the value at `buffer[2]` you need to do the reverse of `memcpy()`, which is another `memcpy()`, as follows:

```
uint16_t u16;
memcpy(&u16, buffer+2, 2);
cout << u16 << endl;
```

Comment: ohhhhhhh. 1.5 hours i wasted i did'

Comment: well, actually, this kind of waste of time tends to happen a lot, sometimes even to experienced programmers, so don't be discouraged. But try to learn to use a debugger, it is very useful in situations like this.